A guy controls his friend's mind and makes him fall off the terrace
Made in: Before 2000's (most probably)
Watched in: Beginning of 2000's
Only scene remembered: There is a party going on at a patio/terrace or a penthouse. There is a guy who has a super power that he can control mind or make things move (telekinesis). People press him to show his super power at the party. So he decides to demonstrate on his friend. I think he levitated his friend and made him walk on the air. Then things go wrong and his friend falls off the terrace.
Not: Chronicles (2012)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FDqROn5-sEM
What genre was it?

@Davidenko: Not, "Zapped Again". Genre is sci-fi and thriller.

"Scanners III: The Takeover." 
I cannot find a video online for this, but I did find a reference in an Amazon review that mentions the balcony scene. The hero accidentally pushes his friend off the balcony and runs off to a monastery to get in touch with his inner power. 
http://www.amazon.com/Scanners-3-Takeover-Liliana-Komorowska/dp/6302353874
